# java.util not working in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio-2010, zip

I was using java.util.zip for extracting zip files in c# visual studio 2005 project,

but when I upgraded the project to visual studio 2010 it doesn't compile anymore and throwing following error

```
"The type or namespace name 'java' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

Is java or java.util is missing in visual studio 2010? What should I do to add this in my project?

Comment: @Pluc [yep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx).

Comment: You can't use visual studio as an IDE for java.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Interesting but I don't really see why someone would use that! :)

Comment: In visual studio 2005 you could use J# in c# project, I used it for extracting zip files as there was no better alternative present in c# at that time.

Comment: @MansoorAziz - J# isn't Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J# was [discontinued in VS 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb188593). You'll need to install the J# 2.0 Redistributable package (linked from the same page) and add an appropriate reference in your C# project.

Alternatively, you could use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) or another third party library.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I think using SharpZibLib or DotnetZipLib(http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) would be better option.